# How to dynamically validation under ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello I am beginner of Angularjs and I want to build dynamic validations.Here is my code shortened as well as possible.

**JS**

```
$scope.inputValidates = [
      { 'name':'name',
        'validate':'required',
      },
      { 'name':'email',
        'validate':'type = email',
      }]
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="vitem in vm.inputValidates">
          <input name={{vitem.name}} ng-model="vm.useraccount[vitem.name]"             {{item.validate}}>
</div>
```

I want this input result as

```
<input name=name ng-model="vm.useraccount[vitem.name]    required>
<input name=name ng-model="vm.useraccount[vitem.name]    type = email>
```

Thanks for taking time for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ng-required](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired):

```
<div ng-repeat="vitem in vm.inputValidates">
    <input name={{vitem.name}} ng-model="vm.useraccount[vitem.name]" ng-required="item.validate">
</div>
```

By the way, I see you assigned `inputValidates` to your `$scope`. So you should be accessing it in your view by `inputValidates`, not `vm.inputValidates`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but still i have a issue. If i use 'ng-required="item.validate"' I can only use required validation isn'it?How about some other validation?

Comment: You're right. What you seem to need then is to dynamically add directives inside `ng-repeat`, which I am not sure to be something a beginner should dive in. Do these inputs really need to be inside a `ng-repeat`? Maybe you could reconsider this and have a look at AngularJS validations (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Answer (score 0):

Sample is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/99ufw318/2/)**

Sample contains both required and pattern validation applied on textbox rendered using ng-repeat and use ng-switch based on your validation type

```
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
   <div style="width:600px">
      <div ng-form name="validMe" style="width:58%;float:left" ng-switch="field.validationType">
         {{field.name}} :
         <div ng-switch-when="required">
            <input id="input{{$index}}"  name="input{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="field.value" required> 
            <span style="color: #a94442" ng-show="validMe['input\{\{$index\}\}'].$error.required ">Field Required!</span>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="email">
            <input type="email" id="input{{$index}}"  name="input{{$index}}" ng-model="field.value" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/">
            <span style="color: #a94442" ng-show="validMe['input\{\{$index\}\}'].$error.pattern">Not a valid email!</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```